# iPad dismiss popover with button within the popover itself

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller, dismiss, appdelegate

I have a button in my popover controller. I want to use it to dismiss the popover, so I am trying to access a method (dismissPopover) of the presenting view controller (the "root" view controller).

**Note:** the method to dismiss the popover is already set up and working, in the root VC, which is the delegate. If I call it it will dismiss the popover. I just need to access the method from the popover.

To do this I set up a property in the AppDelegate, and get an instance of the rootVC like this: `self.rootController = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;`. Then I imported the root VC class and the AppDelegate to the popover's view controller's class, as below. Seems to give me access to the rootVC, and the methods, but the results do not fire the method. Any idea what I am missing here?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Action connected to button:

```
- (IBAction)dismissPopover:(id)sender {

//Checking the button works, it does:
NSLog(@"dismissPopover, from popover");

//Trying to get an instance of the rootViewController, the "presenting view controller"                                  
ViewController *rootVC = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] rootController];

//trying to access the method in the rootVC that dismisses the popover
[rootVC dismissPopover];

//Tried the following code, does nothing:
//[self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

**NOTE:** I ended up abandoning the use of a popover for this as it became a bit over complicated. I tried loading my view controller into a UIView (so I could load the contents of a nib to a pop-up view). That also became a bit complicated. So, for now I am just building my desired interface in a UIView programatically. So far works great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `dismissPopoverAnimated:` is a method of `UIPopoverController` class.  so, you need a popover controller reference in your 'root' view controller.

   ```
   MyRootViewController.myPopoverController = thePopover;
   ```
2. the button is in your 'root' view controller, and in it's action method:

   ```
   [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   ```

Comment: Interesting. Well the method already works form the class I am trying to access. Just need to access the method from the popover and I'm done, I think. But I will give your solution some thought.

Answer (score 8):

In iOS 8, you can dismiss the popover (if it's coming from a segue, at least) with `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` from within the popover. Doesn't work in iOS 7 (or below), however.

Comment: This is what I did intuitively, and the popover disappears. Problem is: My PopoverPresentationControllerDelegate isn't called when I do this programmatically. But IT IS called, if I tap outside the popover so it gets dismissed automatically. Is there anything else I need to do, so that my delegate is properly informed?

Answer (score 3):

Popover automatically dismissed when clicking outside it , as you order a button to dismiss it you can simply use the following code inside your dismissPopover method :

```
         [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

you don't need all this tedious work !

Comment: Thanks! But I know that. I don't want it to dismiss when you tap outside of it. I only want it to dismiss when a button is tapped. This is to save me some more tedious work in other areas by the way.

Comment: i mean it, use this method inside your action method so as to dismiss it, i use it in a similar case BTW

Comment: property 'popoverController' not found on object of type 'X *'

Answer (score 1):

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

is the solution;
you just need an IBoutlet or add target to your button and then call above line

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem

just do in your buttonClickMethod:

```
[yourPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

hope you help!

cheers